# Significance of [[ "$var" ]] in bash

Tags: bash, if-statement

I have difficulty figuring out what this does

```
if [[ "$invoke" ]]; then
```

Have looked at the bash manual which is 190 pages long and could not identify the relavant part that might help me understand.

Comment: `[[ ... ]]` are conditional expressions. Search for CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS in the bash manual. You'll see that this is the same as `[[ -n "$invoke" ]]`, that is, true if the length of the string is not zero.

Comment: Is this because it just says `string` below `-n string` ?

Comment: Yes, this means that they are the same.

Comment: Note that when looking at the bash manual (`man bash`) you can perform searches. In this case you must escape the square brackets because they have a special meaning in search expressions. Just type slash-backslash-[-backslash-[-return (`/\[\[`) and you'll find the first occurrence of `[[` in the manual. Then type `n` to go to the next occurrence or `N` to go to the previous occurrence.

Comment: Thank you so very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bash(1) says:

> ```
> [[ expression ]]
> ```
>
> Return a status of 0 or 1 depending on the evaluation of the conditional expression expression.  Expressions are composed of the primaries described below under CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS.  Word splitting and pathname  expansion are not performed on the words between the [[ and ]]; tilde expansion, parameter and variable expansion, arithmetic expansion, command substitution, process substitution, and quote removal are performed.  Conditional operators such as -f must be unquoted to be recognized as primaries.

and later in the CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS section:

> ```
> string
> -n string
> ```
>
> True if the length of string is non-zero.